# How to test if a value is exactly 0.0 in shader nodes?

Tags: mathematics, shader-nodes

I have a node setup where I need to test whether or not a value is exactly 0.

Blender's math node has a comparison mode but it uses an epsilon value to check if a value is within a certain tolerance, but I want to know if a value is exactly 0.

How do I do that?

Comment: Why don't you just make the tolerance equal to 0?

Comment: Stupidly asked: Doesn't this work by setting Epsilon to $0$?

Comment: Yeah that is definitely the solution ^^. Only thing to keep in mind is if you set the compare value to 0 with an epsilon of 0 on some gradient from 0 to 1 it's going to show completely black and you won't be able to "see" the result.

Comment: So setting Epsilon to 0 actually works? I always thought that epsilon meant strictly greater than and not greater equal than?

Comment: [Epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) can be understood here as "tolerance".

Comment: @quellenform I tried to find the source code regarding the comparison operation but coulsn't find it can you help here?

Comment: [Source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/nodes/function/nodes/node_fn_compare.cc#L170)

Comment: Thanks man! Why do the functions all have such weird names...

Comment: Ok I had a look at it. It really is divergence<=epsilon. Apart from that it also seems to define cases which are not accessible in Blender.